# MacOS Sonoma - How to disable CRTL+SPACE shortcut?

Tags: macos, macos-sonoma

On IDE's like visual studio for MAC, CTRL+SPACE is a shortcut for "give me possible completions", like, if you type `MyObject.Query` and hit ctrl+space you would a dropbox of suggestions like

```
.QueryAsync(string username, myFilter filters)
.QueryByUserName(string username)
.QueryByUserId(int userId)
```

Now with Sonoma, CTRL+SPACE is F****** "change language input"... how can I change that behavior and clear it so the IDE gets the keystroke?

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Input Sources and uncheck everything

Comment: That's always been the default, but I don't know why it would reset itself on an update if it was off before - unless you did a clean OS install.